# запуск powershell скрипта из java

Tags: java

```
public class Main {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
  Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process;
        String cmd[] = {"powershell", "c:/none.ps1"};
        //String cmd[] = {"notepad","c:/snd.txt"};
        System.out.println(cmd);
        try {
            process = runtime.exec(cmd);
        } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ups");
        }
    }
```

Пытаюсь запустить shell скрипт из java, но ничего не происходит. Обычный txt запускается без проблем. В чем проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте `String cmd[] = {"cmd", "powershell c:/none.ps1"};`

Comment: Igor, скрипт так и не отрабатывает

Comment: У меня все работает :) Как проверили, что скрипт не отрабатывает? Что получится если в скрипте записать что-нибудь в файл (`set-content "output.txt" "bla-bla"`)?

Comment: сам скрипт `Get-Process powershell | Out-File out.txt`  проверяю .txt, если запускать руками в out.txt пишутся данные, запускаю через java код ничего не происходит. голову уже сломал.

Comment: Java запускается в той же папке где находится/запускается скрипт? Если нет, то проверьте не появляется ли файл в папке запуска Java. Либо попробуйте прописать абсолютный путь к файлу в скрипте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось следующим:
в `String cmd` "кладем" `"cmd /c powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File c:/none.ps1"` после этого `build`им артефакт, запускаем и скрипт полностью отрабатывает.
весь код:

```
public class Main {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
  Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process;
        String cmd = "cmd /c powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File c:/none.ps1";
        try {
            process = runtime.exec(cmd);
        } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
            System.out.println("point");
        }
    }
```